# How to overlay Geom_Point and Geom_Boxplot in (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to overlay a 'Geom_Point' Colored by color, with 'Geom_Boxplot' that does not contain the color aesthetic.

I want to overlay these plots

```
ggplot(Spheriod, aes(Cellline_Stim, Total.Area, colour = Experiment.No.)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.8)
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N088l.png)
and

```
ggplot(Spheriod, aes(Cellline_Stim, Total.Area)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

[And this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5H0Js.png)

My attempt is:

```
ggplot(Spheriod, aes(Cellline_Stim, Total.Area, colour = Experiment.No.)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.8)
```

However, this creates 3 different boxplots per Experiment no. [Not what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qff8.png)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, don't put `color` in global aesthetics

```r
ggplot(Spheriod, aes(Cellline_Stim, Total.Area)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = Experiment.No.), alpha = 0.8)
```

`geom_jitter` will make your plot more readable than `geom_point`

Comment: Cool ! Then, would you mind accepting the answer ? ([see guidelines if needed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))